# msg.value raises error and doesn't send eth to contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to write a simple Contract in Remix and cannot find a solution for the following problem: Trying to transfer a specific amount of Ethereum to the contract.

The contract compiles and deploys without any problems.
But when I try to call the function I get the following error message you can see on the picture below. The problem can't be not enough Ethereum, I got about 2 Ethereum on the Rinkeby Testnetwork.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2hXj.png

I can click on "Send Transaction" which will open up Metamask:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vba66.png

And after a few seconds the transaction fails... :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT9hy.png

I am using the msg.value() function. My code is the following:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Contract {
    function sendEth() public payable {
        require(msg.value > .02 ether, "Not enough ETH");
    }
}
```

If anyone got a hint, I would really appreciate it, cause I am on it for way too long now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third screenshot shows that you're sending 0 wei along with the transaction. So the require condition in your Solidity code fails, as 0 is not more than 0.02 ether.

A contract is not able to pull any ETH from your wallet - you need to specify how much you want to send with the transaction.

In Remix, there's a "Value" input in the "Deploy and run transactions" tab that allows you to specify the amount.